# iOS HTML Editing Issue

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I have a webView and when you open one view it takes the webView and gets the html (through javascript) and the problem is that when I try to load the edited html, it comes up funny looking, like it is missing the images and its mostly text and not as nice. For example: If I go on Yahoo Mobile and I change the Today Tab to say say lets say Hi, then it all comes out in one column as hyperlinks instead of with the big search bar, news in the middle etc.

Heres My Code For Retrieving The HTML:

```
-(IBAction)recieveHTML:(id)sender {
htmlView.hidden = NO;
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                  @"document.body.outerHTML"];
NSString *query = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@">\n"];
htmlTView.text = query;
universalURL = url.text;

}
```

Heres My Code For Reloading The HTML:

```
-(IBAction)changeHTML:(id)sender {
[htmlTView resignFirstResponder];
NSString *query = [htmlTView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">\n" withString:@">"];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:query baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:universalURL]];
htmlView.hidden = YES;

}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
universalURL
```

Is that value what you think that value should be? It sounds like it isn't and because of that, the paths to the images and the stylesheets are no longer valid.

If you are just manipulating the strings you might be better off just doing it with javascript instead of reloading the html.

Comment: universal url is empty and that line makes it the currentURL so when u change back its always the right url. As for javascript im not exactly sure how that would work...could you explain?

Comment: That value should not be empty. It needs to be the base URL of the website so that the images and stylesheets load correctly. Look at what is happening when you use it for Yahoo Mobile. CSS is not loading correctly.

Comment: what is the base url of a mobile website, because i cant seem to solve how to get the base...?

Comment: How are you getting the original URL? NSURL actually has a method baseURL that will give you what you need.

Comment: I recieve the currentURL of the webview and use it as the base url...whats the method for base url?